# How do you reconcile the definitions of multiple mutually independent events and multiple mutually independent random variables?

Tags: probability, independence

1) If $A, B, C$ are events then to prove mutual independence it's not enough to show $P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$. You also have to show $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ etc.

2) For random variables, the definition of mutual independence looks different. If $X,Y,Z$ are random variables, then it's enough to show $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$, for every possible value of $X,Y,Z$

The situation is different. In the random variable case each assignment of values to $X,Y,Z$ is a collection of events for which you'd have to show independence as in case 1).

case 2) of course follows from case 1). I am looking for a simple proof, since it seems like it should follow in a straightforward way. Most texts/PDFs simply state it without proof. For example, [here](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/384Gfa08/IndepMorervsslides.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 should read

\begin{equation}
\Pr(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)= \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y) \Pr(Z=z)  \qquad \text{for all x,y,z}
\end{equation}

That this holds for any combination of $x,y,z$ is a strong condition. Recall that we get the marginal distribution of $X,Y$ by summing over $Z$

\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x,Y=y) &= \sum_z \Pr(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) &\qquad\text{marginal distribution}\\
&= \sum_z \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y) \Pr(Z=z) &\qquad\text{assumed condition} \\
&= \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y) \cdot \sum_z  \Pr(Z=z) \\
&= \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y)
\end{align}

so pairwise independence follows. The continuous case is analagous.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement about the definition of independent random variables is
applicable only to *discrete* random variables and not for *continuous*
random variables since in the continuous case what A. Webb writes
as
$$\Pr(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)= \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y) \Pr(Z=z)  \qquad \text{for all} ~x,y,z$$
is trivially satisfied with both sides having value $0$ for all 
choices of $x,y,z$.

A more verbose alternative definition of the mutual stochastic independence of three events $A,B, C$ is that *all eight*
of the following identities must hold:

\begin{align}
\Pr(A\cap B\cap C) &= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C) \tag{1}\\
\Pr(A\cap B\cap C^c) &= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C^c)\tag{2}\\
\Pr(A\cap B^c\cap C) &= \Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)\Pr(C) \tag{3}\\
\Pr(A\cap B^c\cap C^c) &= \Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)\Pr(C^c) \tag{4}\\
\Pr(A^c\cap B\cap C) &= \Pr(A^c)\Pr(B)\Pr(C) \tag{5}\\
\Pr(A^c\cap B\cap C^c) &= \Pr(A^c)\Pr(B)\Pr(C^c)\tag{6}\\
\Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C) &= \Pr(A^c)\Pr(B^c)\Pr(C) \tag{7}\\
\Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c) &= \Pr(A^c)\Pr(B^c)\Pr(C^c) \tag{8}\\
\end{align}
which I hope will seem to you to be eerily akin to checking whether
$$\Pr(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)= \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=y) \Pr(Z=z)$$
holds for **all** $x,y,z$!

These $8$ equalities are a little redundant in that you don't
need to check on *all* of them; checking just a few suffices. 
Note that $(1)$ is an equality that you need to check (you knew
that already!) but if you *also* verify that $(2)$ holds, then
you can *add* $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get that
$$\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\tag{9}$$ holds. Similarly,
after checking $(3)$, adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ shows that
$$\Pr(A\cap C) = \Pr(A)\Pr(C)\tag{10}$$ holds, and the sum
of $(1)$ and $(5)$ is $$\Pr(B\cap C) = \Pr(B)\Pr(C) \tag{11}$$
at which point you can stop.  But, $(1)$-$(8)$ are useful
to keep in mind when dealing with events and their complements:

> the probability of an intersection is the product of the
>   probabilities, regardless of whether we are dealing with
>   mutually independent events or their complements or both.