# If $P(a) = 0.2,\, P(b) = 0.4,\, P(c) = 0.1$ and all are mutually independent, what is $P(A \cap (B' \cap C))$?

Tags: probability

If my title is not clear enough it is asking for P(A AND (B' AND C)).

Mutually independent events, meaning they do not rely upon one another.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: See Equations 1-8 of [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/161280/6633).

Comment: Have you tried drawing the Venn Diagram?

Comment: I'm unsure as to how a venn diagram will help with the numerical values, but I did draw one.

Answer (score 1):

Just some suggestions  $B=(A\cap B)\cup(\bar{A}\cap B)$

$\therefore P(B)=P[(A\cap B)\cup(\bar{A}\cap B)]=P(A\cap B)+P(\bar{A}\cap B)-P(A\cap B\cap \bar{A}\cap B)=P(A\cap B)+P(\bar{A}\cap B)$

Note: $P(A\cap B\cap \bar{A}\cap B)=0$

and $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

Therefore,

$P(B)=P(A)P(B)-P(\bar{A}\cap B)$

Rearrange the terms

$P(\bar{A}\cap B)=P(A)P(B)-P(B)=[1-P(A)]P(B)=P(\bar{A})P(B)$

This shows that $\bar{A}$ and $B$ are independent.

By the same method, you can show if $A,B, C$ are mutually independent, then $A,B,C, \bar{A},\bar{B},\bar{C}$ are all mutually independent.

I think now can start from here.

Comment: Good grief!  Also, it might help to show that $A$ and $B^c$ are independent rather that $A^c$ and $B$ as you have done....

Comment: Yes, that will be more clear.